# How to allow tab to always insert a set number of spaces in Visual Studio (2017)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio 1.19 on Ubuntu (deb). I already killed all the IntelliSense stuff and I wanted to also update tab behaviour. I want a tab to be just a tab. Sometimes when I am commenting (e.g. in C++), it tries to align with the line above and matches that line vertically resulting in more or less then 4 spaces that I desire. I tried playing with User Settings with no luck.

Which settings do I need to amend to achieve specified number of tabs at all times?

Comment: are you referring to vscode or visual studio?

Comment: Visual Studio Code, my bad.